# Flex to Apache Royale migration

Tags: migration, flex3, apache-royale

i have a large scale Application in Flex and i now want to migrate from Flex to Apache Royale.I have zero experience in Apache Royale, in fact i just heard about it few days ago. I need help in migration i already read the documentation of apache Royale but im still having difficulty converting my existing view controller and models as per apache royale standards.

Attached are the three screen shots from my Login screen developed in flex.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now my questions are

1. Is there anything that i can reuse while migrating.I added the controller,view and model from flex i got a lot of issues. mx application is the first thing that is giving error. Royale is using fx:appliaction instead. i guess most of my UI will be replaced with new tags from Rotale?
2. what should i do with the following imports

   import mx.core.Application

   import mx.events.FlexEvent

   import mx.binding.utils.ChangeWatcher

   import mx.binding.utils.BindingUtils

what are their alternatives?

**Please Review attached Images and Suggest alternatives**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to join Apache Royale's [mailing list](https://royale.apache.org/mailing-lists/), since starting a whole migration is not an easy task that could be solve here. This place is better for concrete questions and answers, while you'll need people that could guide you in your starting journey.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using Moonshine IDE? Some of these errors will go away if you go to Additional Compiler Options and set
+configname=flex?

Also, if you're on a tight schedule you might want to check out Royale's commercial support page [1].

[1] https://royale.apache.org/royale-commercial-support/